# dynamic cell ranges VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro I am working on. It detects if a cell has a value of NA if it does it run a piece of code.

**Problem:** So far i am able to only run it on one cell. I am trying to apply the below cells to my macro.

Sheet3.Range D ( 20, 24, 25, 27, 28, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 37, 38, 40, 42, 43, 44, 54, 55, 56, 58, 59, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65)

Sheet3.Range E ( 20, 24, 25, 27, 28, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 37, 38, 40, 42, 43, 44, 54, 55, 56, 58, 59, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
Dim sCellVal As String

sCellVal = Range("D20")

If sCellVal Like "*NA*" Then

    Range("D20") = "Not applicable" & "  " & Environ("Username") & "  " & Format(Now, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")

End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a reason why the macro can't be run on for example D21 D22 and D23? If not you could just iterate over all cells From D20 to D65. So you could define a range of D20 - D65 and then do a : For each cell in range.

Comment: @Luuklag i want to macro to be applied to the above cells only. My question how can i rewrite the code that all the cells are included.

Answer (score 1):

there is an alternative approach. You could follow these steps:

1. Use a IFERROR(cellReferenceHere;functionName())
2. Write it as Public Function on VBA.

It will trigger always when #N/A happens

Example:
Cell:

```
=IFERROR(0/0;doSomething())
```

VBA:

```
Public Function doSomething()
    doSomething = "Done"
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any obvious logic for the rows used in this range, so we'll sort of hard-code the row numbers in a `Case` switch and then check against the `Target.Row`

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    '// Check if the target row number is in our array:
    Select Case Target.Row
        Case 20, 24, 25, 27, 28, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 37, 38, 40, 42, 43, 44, 54, 55, 56, 58, 59, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65
            ' Do Something
            If Cstr(Target.Value) Like "*NA*" Then

                Target.Value = "Not applicable" & "  " & Environ("Username") & "  " & Format(Now, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")

            End If

        Case Else
            ' Do nothing
            Exit Sub
    End Select
End Sub
```

Note: if you're looking for *error* values, rather than doing the string comparison with `Like` operator, check for true error equivalence:

```
If Target.Value = CvErr(2042) Then 
    Target.Value = "Not applicable" & "  " & Environ("Username") & "  " & Format(Now, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I just made an array and did a quick loop on the array to look at all of the ranges and test the condition.

```
Sub test()
Dim D As Variant
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim x As Integer


D = Array(20, 24, 25, 27, 28, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 37, 38, 40, 42, 43, 44, 54, 55, 56, 58, 59, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65)


For x = LBound(D) To UBound(D)
Set rng1 = Cells(D(x), 4)
Set rng2 = Cells(D(x), 5)
If rng1 Like "*NA*" Then
rng1 = "Not applicable" & "  " & Environ("Username") & "  " & Format(Now, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
End If
If rng2 like "*NA*" then 
   rng2 = "Not applicable" & "  " & Environ("Username") & "  " & Format(Now, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
End if
Next x


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be a discernible pattern to the ranges, so I've hardcoded them into an array. This does what you need, but I'll leave it to you to create the array for Column E:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change()
Dim ws_data As Worksheet
Dim arr_Range(0 To 9) As String
Dim i as Integer

Set ws_data = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data") 'change to your sheet name

arr_Range(0) = "D20"
arr_Range(1) = "D24:D25"
arr_Range(2) = "D27:D28"
arr_Range(3) = "D30:D35"
arr_Range(4) = "D37:D38"
arr_Range(5) = "D40"
arr_Range(6) = "D42:D44"
arr_Range(7) = "D54:D56"
arr_Range(8) = "D58:D59"
arr_Range(9) = "D61:D65"

'Loop through array
For i = LBound(arr_Range) To UBound(arr_Range)
    For Each Cell In ws_data.Range(arr_Range(i)) 'check each cell in the current range string in the array
        If Cell.Value Like "*NA*" Then
            Cell.Value = "Not applicable" & "  " & Environ("Username") & "  " & Format(Now, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
        Else: End If
    Next Cell
Next i
End Sub
```